# What's the name of this kind of typography combining multiple words into a shape?

Tags: typography, illustration

I need to know the exact name of below typography technique or the phrase designers use to mention these kinds of artworks.

Is there any app or online service to make such images?

[image]

Comment: Hi silvercover, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help] or ping one of us in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/the-ink-spot) once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those are usually mean *word clouds*.

You can use [this site](http://www.wordle.net/) easily for creating a word cloud.

Comment: Hi Dishan, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your answer. If you have any questions, please see the [help] or ping one of us in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/the-ink-spot) once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 2):

The term I think you're looking for is 'tag cloud', or 'word cloud'. The average tag cloud doesn't regularly include custom shapes like the arrow on the lower left of your example, but the term is close enough.

It seems you can create great word clouds with [Wordle](http://www.wordle.net/).

Comment: Glad you mentioned 'tag cloud'. The [Wikipedia article on tag clouds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tag_cloud) has a good overview of the history of these graphics.